# Do a docker-compose in visual studio, for a certain configuration

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm creating a docker composition in Visual Studio 2022. I have a C# (.net framework 4.7.2) project, that has several transformed Web.Config files (one for each configuration).

When I do my docker-compose, I see that it uses the base configuration, and not the currently selected configuration in Visual Studio.

Is there any way I can have the composition use the transformed config file?